# Desktop locks up, Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, desktop-environments

A few days ago, after applying an upgrade, I will login at the Lubuntu session screen and desktop starts to load and desktop icons appear but clicking them does nothing and no menu or taskbar either. After a few minutes the screen is black with just the pointer that no longer moves.

Comment: FYI:  You're aware that Lubuntu 20.04 LTS was a *flavor* of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and came with 3 years of supported life? (refer https://lubuntu.me/lubuntu-20-04-lts-end-of-life-and-current-support-statuses/ reaching the end of its three year supported life) with 5 years applying to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu base but not *flavors*. Your LXQt desktop has received no upgrades, only your base system gets upgrades; so I'd look for a change you made yourself for clues. You're still on-topic here with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS questions (*even if using LXQt*)

Comment: @guiverc I should've been more clear, it wasnt an OS upgrade but a popup that alerted me of an update. These typically are for apps I have installed like Firefox or the megasync app. After it completed it prompted for a reboot and thats when the issue started. I didnt see what was updated as I had it run in background. I did remove the megasync app but no change.

Comment: My comment was made as an *Informational post* only (ie. FYI).  Your question is still on-topic as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is still supported (even if Lubuntu 20.04 is EOL); as packages from *main* still have a security guarantee (Lubuntu/LXQt was from *universe* which no longer has any guarantee of fixes unless Ubuntu Pro is utilized; though its still possible for MOTU's to upload fixes until 20.04 reaches EOSS)...

Comment: Just updating. This issue must have been related to LXQT as I could NOT get it to load even after removing/purging lubuntu-desktop and GDM3 and reinstalling, but I could install another desktop and that launched just fine. So I ended up just switching to KDE and no idea why Lubuntu would not load?

Comment: The Lubuntu team have made no changes since the release went EOL (28 April 2023 - https://lubuntu.me/lubuntu-20-04-lts-end-of-life-and-current-support-statuses/ with notice pasted 1 May 2023; LXQt hasn't changed). All *flavor* support is 3 years only.  (Lubuntu/LXQt uses `sddm` not `gdm3` which is a GNOME display manager)